# Django Allauth asking for password 3 times in signup page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to implement a signup form with django-allauth and everything works as it should. However I've implemented a `CustomUserCreationForm` that displays the fields listed below and since then its been asking for the password 3 times. I only want to ask for the password once but it seems to add the password and password confirmation fields automatically now (see image below). Even if I remove all fields the two password fields still remain. In my settings I've already set the `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False` but still shows the password field three times. Any help would be appreciated!

#### Forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "mobile", "email", "password")
```

#### Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default="")
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12, default="")
```

#### Allauth settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"
SITE_ID = 1
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = "home"
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {"signup": "accounts.forms.CustomUserCreationForm"}
```

#### HTML Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("first_name", "last_name", "mobile")
```

Note that you only need to add custom fields. In your case you added password while it is already there [1].

Regarding the ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE, which version of Django are you using?
Does ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION work? This setting was used pre-release 0.26.0 (2016-07-24) [2].

Ref [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Ref [2]: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE#id60

Answer (score 0):

You are using **django-allauth**, if you want to use settings of **django-allauth** you have to import `SignupForm` from `allauth`.

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=55, label=_("First Name"))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=55, label=_("Last Name"))
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=12, label=_("Mobile"))

    class Meta:
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "mobile", "email", "password")

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)

        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.mobile = self.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
        user.save()

        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

settings.py (for the future seekers):

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {"signup": "yourapp.forms.CustomUserCreationForm"}
```

Look also at [**django-allauth**](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform) docs.

Comment: I tried this but the it only displays the email and 1 password field which is what I want but its not displaying the first_name, last_name or mobile fields